# Directional Derivative is Linear

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:R^n \to R$ be differentiable and $\lambda_i \in R$ for $i=1,\dotsc,n$. Why does
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+t\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e_i)-f(x)}{t}=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+te_i)-f(x)}{t}$$
hold?

Comment: A good start would be to discuss where you are stuck after applying the definition.

Comment: Start by showing that for any vectors $u, v$, $$\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{g(tu + tv) - g(0)}t = \lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{g(tu) - g(0)}t + \lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{g(tv) - g(0)}t$$ and that $$\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{g(t\lambda u) - g(0)}t = \lambda \lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{g(tu) - g(0)}t$$ Then consider $g(y) = f(x + y)$. The rest is induction. For clues on how to do those two, go back and study the proofs of the chain, sum, and constant multiplier rules for 1D calculus.